# WPF Custom Control with Dependency Property binding to DockPanel.Dock Attached Property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I’m attempting to create a custom control with 4 states (Top, Bottom, Left, Right), and each of these states needs to update the DockPanel.Dock attached property which is attached to an Image control in the control's template.

A portion of my control template is as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type library:IndicatorButton}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Image x:Name="Icon" 
        DockPanel.Dock="{TemplateBinding State}" Height="66" Width="87"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{DynamicResource HandIcon}"/>

    <Border Background="{x:Null}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
    </Border>
```

And the “State” property is defined as a dependency property like so

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(HandIndicatorStates),
        typeof(IndicatorButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HandIndicatorStates.None,
        OnIndicatorStateChanged){
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
  });
```

HandIndicatorStates is an enum which is defined as follows

```
public enum HandIndicatorStates
{
    Left = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Bottom = 3,
    None = 4
}
```

And finally i’m defining the control in the xaml like so

```
<library:IndicatorButton State="Top" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="5"/>
```

When I change the “State” property in the control definition, nothing happens. But when I remove the template binding in the control template and replace it with “Top”, “Bottom” etc I get the required results.

I’m sure this is something I’m not doing in the custom control code that I should be. I've omitted some stuff to try and keep this short and sweet, but if you need anything else please ask

Thank you for any help

Comment: does the State set properly at the start i.e like in your question you have set State as Top, does it set on image on start ?

Comment: I am guessing it is because your DP needs to use type [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.dock(v=vs.100).aspx), while you have it set to type `HandIndicatorStates`, which can't be converted to a `Dock` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property is of type [System.Windows.Controls.Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock.aspx) while the property you are binding to is of your own custom enum type.

That is not going to work, and you should be getting a binding error in the output window in Visual Studio that indicates this.

To make it work, you can attach a `IValueConverter` to the binding, which simply maps between the different enum types.

I have written a very small program that shows how it can be done. There is no `ControlTemplate` or anything like that, but yours has nothing to do with the actual problem.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public HandIndicatorStates State
    {
        get { return HandIndicatorStates.Top; }
    }
}

public enum HandIndicatorStates
{
    Left = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Top = 2,
    Bottom = 3,
    None = 4
}

public class StateToDockEnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        HandIndicatorStates state = (HandIndicatorStates)value;

        if (state == HandIndicatorStates.None)
            return null; //??

        // Map from HandIndicatorStates to Dock enum by name.
        var dock = Enum.Parse(typeof(Dock), state.ToString());
        return dock;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
        Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StateToDockEnumConverter x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="Dock to top" 
            DockPanel.Dock="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />

    <Button Content="Fill rest" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! Bit disappointed in myself for not figuring this out. Guess I will just put it down to a log day yesterday